# Mac vs PC Text Encoding

Tags: macos, utf-8, character-encoding

I've noticed this different specifically with iTunes when you export your music library.

I have a song with é (that is, a small latin E with an acute accent) and when I export the library in Windows, it gets encoded at %C3%A9, but when I export the library from Mac, a normal 'e' is printed, followed by %CC%81.

Example:

```
Song Name: Héllo World
Windows Export: H%C3%A9llo World
Mac Export: He%CC%81llo World
```

This is important to me for a program I'm making where, in the Windows version, I decode the encoding, but now it doesn't work if the file comes from a Mac.

So why is there this difference? Is there a place I can see the differences and see what the Mac encodings are? Is there maybe an Object-C routine to decode these strings?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`C3A9` is the UTF-8 encoding for the character é.
`CC81` is the UTF-8 encoding for the COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT character (U+0301).

An "e" followed by a COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT combines to the character "é".
The two are simply different forms of [Unicode normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_normalization).

Why one iTunes prefers one over the other I don't know, there's no inherent reason to do so.

Comment: I don't think iTunes prefers either; the underlying OSs no doubt understand both equally but when they have to pick one or the other for output, Microsoft went one way and Apple the other.

Comment: Yes, that's probably it. I don't know in how far iTunes uses the underlying APIs or how much it insists on standardizing the Unicode normalization.

Comment: I don't know about Windows, but the Mac filesystem (HFS+) insists on the decomposed form ("e" + combining accent), so it doesn't matter what iTunes does (well, unless it somehow bypasses the filesystem code...)

Comment: Thanks, that really cleared things up! Does anyone happen to know of a website that shows a list of all the combined encodings?

Comment: In fact, the operating systems act very differently here: Mac OS X converts file names to a variant of normalization form D upon writing, while Windows treats them as opaque sequences of 16-bit units. The OS X behavior is rather unique among operating systems and breaks portability in interesting ways (e.g. if you assume that a filename ends up as passed to the OS on disk, your program won't work on OS X).

Comment: @MrDanA: Apple used to have a developer tech note covering this.  It's been removed, but there's a copy at the internet archive: [tn1150](http://web.archive.org/web/20090214212148/http://developer.apple.com/technotes/tn/tn1150.html#UnicodeSubtleties) and its [decomposition replacement table](http://web.archive.org/web/20090330065329/http://developer.apple.com/technotes/tn/tn1150table.html) may have the info you're looking for.

Comment: Clarification: the table lists unicode code points, not their UTF-8 encodings (e.g. it lists the combining acute accent as 0x0301 instead of CC81).